# Clickonce application has stopped working for WPF application

Tags: vb.net

I have created WPF application on Windows XP using VS 2008. When I published the application, it runs well on XP but it doesnt run on Windows 8 64 bit..I tried installing .net framework 3.5 SP1 on Windows 8 but its not getting installed.
When I run clickonce application,it shows "Projectname.exe has stopped working."
Can any1 help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Think all you need is here: [Installing the .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443.aspx)